# intuitionistic probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, intuitionistic-logic

I wonder whether the law of excluded middle not being available in intuitionistic logic might provide an obstacle when working with an axiomatization of probability theory using the Kolmogorov axioms. More precisely, if we cannot always know whether $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$ for arbitrary $x$, how can we know that $P(A) + P(\Omega \backslash A) = 1$?

So, can the Kolomogorov axioms be reasonably used in intuitionistic logic, or is there a better axiomatization of probability that works well with intuitionistic logic?

Comment: We know $P(A) + P(\Omega \backslash A) = 1$ because Countable Additivity is one of the Kolmogorov axioms.    The issue might be whether we can prove that certain objects satisfy the Kolmogorov axioms.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yes, exactly, which is why I'm wondering whether there is an axiomatization for probabilities which is easily satisfied in intuitionistic logic. After all, Countable Additivity might not work well if there are $x \in \Omega$ where we cannot constructively prove whether they are in sets $A$, $B$, $C$ etc.. We might not be able to prove whether the sets are pairwise disjunct (which is necessary for Countable Additivity), or we might not be able to prove that the union contains $x$.

Comment: You could also simply add that as another axiom. Also you can find a few reference here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139267/is-there-a-probability-theory-developed-in-intuitionistic-logic